# Cannot import org.apache.lucene.search.NumericRangeQuery

Tags: lucene

I added a Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
      <version>9.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but Cannot resolve the symbol 'NumericRangeQuery';
"NumericRangeQuery" should be defined in org.apache.lucene.search. Is this class still there? How Can I import it successfully?
Here is more details about "NumericRangeQuery": https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html

Comment: When I import "Lucene-core 5.2.1-1", there is "NumericRangeQuery". Do you guys know why they deleted it in the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NumericRangeQuery` was deprecated and moved from `org.apache.lucene.search.NumericRangeQuery` to `org.apache.solr.legacy.LegacyNumericRangeQuery`.

You can import it using `import org.apache.solr.legacy.LegacyNumericRangeQuery;`. But I would not recommend to use deprecated API. It is better to migrate your index to the new types and use modern API.